# Не работает вход через прокси в VK

Tags: python

**Пытаюсь зайти через vk api с прокси socks5, в итоге выдает ошибку:** `Unknown error (AUTH; no sid). Please send a bugreport to GitHub: https://github.com/python273/vk_api/issues`

**Аккаунт рабочий, вхожу без проблем без прокси, прокси тоже проверял, они рабочие.**

**Подскажите что делать**

**Код:**

````
def auth_bot():
    try:
        session = Session()
        session.proxies = {'http': 'socks5://*****:******@81.177.26.252:****',
'https': 'socks5://*****:******@81.177.26.252:****'}

        vk_session = VkApi(login_data[1], login_data[2], app_id=2685278, session=session)
        vk_session.auth()
        send_telegram_start_message(cfg.admin_id, '✅', cfg.telegram_token)
        vk = vk_session.get_api()
        run_bot(vk)
        return vk_session
    except vk_api.exceptions.AccountBlocked as e:
        error_message = f"❌ Аккаунт забанен. Удалите его из списка аккаунтов!"
        send_auth_error_to_telegram(error_message)
        return False
    except vk_api.exceptions.ApiError as e:
        error_message = f"❌ Ошибка: {str(e)}"
        send_auth_error_to_telegram(error_message)
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"❌ Неизвестная ошибка: {str(e)}"
        send_auth_error_to_telegram(error_message)
        return False```
````